# Writing an IDE, use GCC to compile

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-construction, ide

I want to write an own c/c++ IDE with syntax-check etc. And of course I need a compiler-functionality. For this I want to use gcc, I think it is a good option, isn't it? The IDE should not call a gcc-binary to compile, it should include the gcc source code, because after compiling the IDE I want a stay alone executable.

So my question: Is there sth like a tutorial or a good hint how to realize this?

btw it's for Mac, I'll write the IDE with XCode

Thank you!

Comment: GCC is a very complex application, and not really made for embedding in other applications. Apple is making a new compiler based on [llvm](http://llvm.org/) which might be more suitable for this. And why can't you just include the GCC (or whatever) binaries in your installation bundle?

Comment: a number of free, publicly available IDE's are open source. NetBeans, Eclipse, Code::Blocks (ignoring the platform specific ones for now)

Comment: Any special reason to make another I.D.E. ? It's a complex project, it could cost you a lot of time, and you may get bored, or leave the project due to school, job, family, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use LLVM's Clang and its libClang API, it's built for this purpose. GCC is not made to be used as a library.

Answer (score 0):

You might develop a plugin for GCC, or a [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension. But it could be that on MacOSX GCC plugins are not supported yet. You might also look into [GCCSense](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/) which might fill some of your goals (but I never used it).